# Standard error for panel data models and heteroscedastic robust SE

Tags: panel-data, standard-error, heteroscedasticity, robust-standard-error

There is something I do not understand on a deeper level on standard errors for panel data models. I know the reason for not using usual heteroscedastic-robust standard-errors is because of auto correlation, and the assumption that this kind of model allows observations to be correlated over time within entity. However I am having problems when trying to sketch a very simple proof of concept. Is there any simple proof that I could use to answer my question? this would help me understand better the concept.